# Can WITH clause have hardcoded values with out using Select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a situation where i need to join two different databases (both are oracle and i don't have DB link) to get my result. I am wondering if i can create a subquery using WITH clause with all the hardcoded values to join to the other table in other database. I tried something like below

```
WITH TEMP AS (SELECT '8108428','8110729' FROM DUAL)
```

but it is giving the values as columns, but i need them under one column as rows, so i can join to other table. Can someone please help me a solution? I have used WITH clause previously but that had a query with in it, but this will have to take the hardcoded values only

Appreciate your responses!

Comment: Quick fix: `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I have 1000s of values, so UNION ALL is not viable choice as i have to repeat the Select in WITH clause as many times as my number of values

Comment: Other than db link, you can export to csv and create an external table in oracle.

Comment: How do you "have" the thousands of values? Are they in a table already? Are they coming from another source? Understand that you are asking the wrong question; you ask "how do I do <this> with two values in the WITH clause", but then it turns out the issue is that you have thousands of values, not how to use the WITH clause. Perhaps the WITH clause isn't even the best tool.

Comment: For example: you could create a JSON array as a CLOB in one database, copy that JSON (by whatever means) to the other database, then use the data from the JSON just as if it was a table, with the `JSON_TABLE` function. Three very simple steps.

Comment: I just showed a sample as what i tried with WITH clause. I am getting the values from different database, so no way i can do a direct join. Also our organization doesn't allow to create a temp tables which would have solved the problem. So i am thinking of other solution, if its doable. So far i have exported data from both tables and running a macro to find my result set, but wondering if that can be achieved with in SQL

Comment: @user15906795 To augment mathguy's comment, if you have 1000s of values, then they belong in a table. External tables have their own performance problems. Avoid them except when you might execute a one time migration into a "internal" table.

Comment: You do not need to repeat something at all, because you can build such long `union` with simple concatenation and spool of the query result that generates those IDs.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a collection type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE varchar2_10_table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
```

Then if you were expecting to do something, for example, like:

```sql
WITH TEMP ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '8108428' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '8110729' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  id IN ( SELECT value FROM temp )
```

Then you can just replace the `WITH` clause with the collection:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  id IN ( SELECT value FROM TABLE( varchar2_10_table( '8108428','8110729' ) ) )
```

or using the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  id MEMBER OF varchar2_10_table( '8108428','8110729' )
```

Or, if you want to keep the `WITH` clause and unpack the collection's values into it then:

```sql
WITH TEMP ( value ) AS (
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( varchar2_10_table( '8108428','8110729' ) )
)
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  id IN ( SELECT value FROM temp )
```

or, keeping the collection in the `WITH` clause:

```sql
WITH TEMP ( collection_value ) AS (
  SELECT varchar2_10_table( '8108428','8110729' ) FROM DUAL
)
SELECT y.*
FROM   your_table y
       INNER JOIN temp t
       ON ( y.id MEMBER OF t.collection_value )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
WITH TEMP AS (
              SELECT '8108428'FROM DUAL
              union all
              SELECT '8110729' FROM DUAL 
             )
```

Comment: I have 1000s of values, so UNION ALL is not viable choice as i have to repeat the Select in WITH clause as many times as my number of values

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get your data as XMLTYPE or JSON, for example:

Get your data as XMLTYPE on the first database:

```sql
select xmltype(cursor(select table_name,num_rows from user_tables)) xmldata from dual;

XMLDATA
----------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <TABLE_NAME>MY_DUAL</TABLE_NAME>
  <NUM_ROWS>1</NUM_ROWS>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <TABLE_NAME>T</TABLE_NAME>
  <NUM_ROWS>10000</NUM_ROWS>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <TABLE_NAME>T1</TABLE_NAME>
  <NUM_ROWS>1000</NUM_ROWS>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <TABLE_NAME>T_DEL</TABLE_NAME>
  <NUM_ROWS>2678541</NUM_ROWS>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

And use it on another database:

```sql
SQL> select *
  2  from xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW'
  3  passing xmltype(q'[<?xml version="1.0"?>
  4  <ROWSET>
  5   <ROW>
  6    <TABLE_NAME>MY_DUAL</TABLE_NAME>
  7    <NUM_ROWS>1</NUM_ROWS>
  8   </ROW>
  9   <ROW>
 10    <TABLE_NAME>T</TABLE_NAME>
 11    <NUM_ROWS>10000</NUM_ROWS>
 12   </ROW>
 13   <ROW>
 14    <TABLE_NAME>T1</TABLE_NAME>
 15    <NUM_ROWS>1000</NUM_ROWS>
 16   </ROW>
 17   <ROW>
 18    <TABLE_NAME>T_DEL</TABLE_NAME>
 19    <NUM_ROWS>2678541</NUM_ROWS>
 20   </ROW>
 21  </ROWSET>
 22  ]')
 23  columns
 24    TABLE_NAME,
 25    NUM_ROWS number
 26  );

TABLE_NAME                       NUM_ROWS
------------------------------ ----------
MY_DUAL                                 1
T                                   10000
T1                                   1000
T_DEL                             2678541
```

Comment: The JSON way is much simpler still.

Comment: First of all, json in oracle is still very unstable and buggy. Second, there is no such convenient constructor like xmltype(cursor)) for json.

Comment: And you are always welcome to post your own answer, without pinging me with your comments to my answers.

Comment: I will comment on any answers I think is appropriate - sometimes the respondent doesn't like it, that's OK. In this case, since you wrote the answer already, I thought perhaps you would like to add the JSON approach yourself. Since you clearly don't feel like it, I just posted that myself, as you suggested. As to "JSON in Oracle is still very unstable and buggy" - I don't agree; that was true for 12.1, but at least since 12.2 it's been fine, especially for the trivial application to this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Three step process:

1. Create a JSON string (a JSON array encoding your values).
2. By whatever means (likely outside the databases, since you said you
   can't make them talk to each other), "copy" this string from the
   source db to the target db.
3. In the target db, call `json_table` on the string. You can use that
   directly in any query that requires the "source" table - in my
   example below, I extract the data in a view in the `with` clause, so
   you can use it as if the "source" table existed in the target db.

I am not showing Step 2 below, since that is not really on the database side. You can copy the string from the first query's output, and email it to yourself, or save it in a file and email the file, and then import from the file on the target side.

For Step 1, suppose I need to copy the "names" from `SCOTT.EMP`. That is as easy as

```
select json_arrayagg(ename) as json_str from scott.emp;
```

The result looks like this (note that I added a linebreak for readability, it is not actually in the output):

```
JSON_STR
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
["SMITH","ALLEN","WARD","JONES","MARTIN","BLAKE","CLARK","SCOTT",
 "KING","TURNER","ADAMS","JAMES","FORD","MILLER"]
```

For Step 3, suppose I copied that long string and pasted it in the query below. (You may need something different to move the string from one place to the other - left to you to think about.) The view created in the `with` clause replaces the view you were trying to create in your original question.

```
with
  local_emp_copy (emp) as (
    select ename
    from   json_table(
             '["SMITH","ALLEN","WARD","JONES","MARTIN","BLAKE","CLARK","SCOTT",
               "KING","TURNER","ADAMS","JAMES","FORD","MILLER"]'
             , '$[*]' columns ename varchar2 path '$')
  )
select emp from local_emp_copy  --  or do whatever you need with the view
;
  
EMP      
---------
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
TURNER
ADAMS
JAMES
FORD
MILLER
```

In your original question, you were creating a view with a column of strings, even though those strings were actually numbers. If the values are numbers, not strings, you shouldn't enclose them in quotes. In the JSON approach, if you have a column of numbers, the first step is the same. In step 3, in the `columns` clause of `json_table`, change the data type of the column to `number`. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` operator, passing tuples to it, which allow more than 1000 values inside. This way you will not need to worry about how to pass long string literal to database.

```
select *
from dual
where (1, dummy) in (
  (1, 'X'),
  (1, 'X')
)
```

*[db<>fiddle is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=350aff613063b556e475fa729f50b6df)*

What about generation of this list of tuples:

- You can export your result with IDs from the first database in Excel as you do now and generate the list by concatenation.
- You can generate it with the same `select` statement from SQL*Plus/SQL Developer using [`spool`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve043.htm#SQPUG126):

```
set heading off
set feedback off
set pages 0
set linesize 1000
set colsep ' '
set serveroutput on
spool c:\temp\myresult.txt

select
  '(1,' ,
  id_col,
  ')' as tuple
from my_source_table;

spool off
```

Answer (score 0):

Every SELECT returns a table, and every column in a table must have a name; thus, what you need is column names in your Common Table Expression:

```
WITH cteTEMP AS (SELECT '8108428' AS SOME_VAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT '8110729' AS SOME_VAL FROM DUAL) 
SELECT *
  FROM cteTemp
```

Later in a comment you mention that you have thousands of values. Perhaps you can use a regular expression to parse your values out of a string:

```
WITH cteCsv AS (SELECT '8108428,8110729' AS CSV FROM DUAL),
     cteVals AS (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(CSV, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS SOME_VAL
                   FROM CSV
                   CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(CSV, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT *
  FROM cteVals
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60c16145e9ebbf68fb01dd60e6427c6c)